# Where is Visual Studio 2015 Cordova project path to Typescript?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I created a Typescript blank Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015.

I add a small test bit of ts code...

```
 function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
        var i: string;
        i = "test";
    }
```

build and see that this has successfully been compiled into the appbundle.js where I see.

```
  function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
        var i;
        i = "test";
    }
```

Now I want to use typescript in vs code as well, and would like both Visual Studio and VS code to use the same version.

I see I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.6` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7`. Neither of these appear in my path variables. If I try and run `tsc` from the command line it is not found.

Opening the project file the only references to typescript I can find are

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />

<PropertyGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>false</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.TypeScript.MDA.targets" />
```

I can't see any reference to it in any other files

If I install using npm, how can I "point" Visual Studio to the new version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing TypeScript via Visual Studio in **Extensions and Updates** and maintain it's version from within there.

Then use NPM to maintain your windows version of TypeScript to what ever version you need. `npm install -g typescript#1.xx`

[image: TypeScript VS]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had seen this extension mentioned elsewhere, so perhaps this is the "proper way" of using it in VS, and we just reply on this extension keeping the TS up to date, and pointing to the correct path. I'll try it and see if I end up with 2 TS folders

Answer (score 1):

Check u path for TypeScript in Environment path.

Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> Path - > Find path for typescript

[Environment path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iD96.png)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I had already looked here .."Neither of these appear in my path variables". Hence also why it is not found at the cmd prompt